# How to turn off auto queue declaration in Spring Boot for existing RabbitMQ queues?

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

We have a number of micore-services. Each micorservice declares and creates its own queues but there is one microservice that listen to some of those queues.

`App A => Creates its own queue A`

`App B => Listens to queue A`

Now the problem is when we modify the queue on say `App A`, e.g. adding dead letter queue or adding `ttl` etc., `App B` fails for example this error:

```
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED 
- inequivalent arg 'x-dead-letter-exchange' for queue 'queue-app-a' in vhost '/': 
  received none but current is the value 'direct-exchange' of type 'longstr', class-id=50, method-id=10)
```

Now this particular error is because on A we've configured dead-letter queue but in B we just left the code as:

```
    @Bean
    public Queue queueAppA() {
        return new Queue("queue-app-a");
    }
```

Is there a way to tell Spring to use existing available queues rather than trying to declare it for `App B`? Otherwise we have to keep these codes all in sync which is painful and errorprone because developers may not even be aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the sender doesnt know anything about the consuming queues. The services you have that sends to the queues doesnt have to know anything about the queues (only the name of the queue).

Then they can just send to the queue name and if the queue exists the message will land there and if it doesnt exist the message will just dissapear.

Only the consuming service should know about the queue (it should only be defined by that service) This way you can avoid the problem you have.

Comment: So you mean we can just use the name as string and no need to instantiate `Queue`?

Comment: Yes exactly. The sender shouldnt care about how the queue is created thats up to the reciever.